# Bold/ italic not working with canvas fillText()

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas element on which I want to put some text using the `fillText()` method.

I am using the following format to do this:

```
ctx.font = "Bold Italic" + myText.fontSize + "px Arial " + myText["font-family"];
```

Here `myText` is a mapping of the following type:

```
var myText = {
              "font-family": "family",
              "fontSize" : "size"
             };
```

The Bold and Italic properties are not working. I don't know what the error is in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below line is missing a space between italic and myText.fontSize:

```
ctx.font = "Bold Italic" + myText.fontSize + "px Arial " + myText["font-family"];
```

So it should be:

```
ctx.font = "Bold Italic " + myText.fontSize + "px Arial " + myText["font-family"];
```

Also, it may just have been for the purposes of your question, but fontSize is not a number, it is the string "size"